# c# A dynamic property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to construct the following

```
CateogoryScores [
    "CatShoes" : 10,
    "CatDress" : 20
]
```

The Catshoes and CatDress are actual values in a database. I need this shape as i need to be able to write the following in javascript. CateogoryScores["CatShoes"] etc

This is my model

```
public class CategoryScoresDTO
{
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string TraqCategoryScore { get; set; }
}
```

This is my function that gets the data from the table

```
private IEnumerable<CategoryScoresDTO> GetCatgoryScoresByBrandId(string brandId)
    {

        var scores = from s in db.CategoryScoresModel
                     where s.BrandId == brandId
                     select new CategoryScoresDTO()
                     {
                         CategoryId = s.CategoryId,
                         TraqCategoryScore = s.TraqCategoryScore
                     };

        return scores;
    }
```

Obviously this is not the shape i want returned as its just a list not it the correct shape i need

Comment: The term "shape" is baffling.  Do you mean that you want to serialize the result to JSON format?

Comment: what do you mean by shape?

Comment: Sorry yes the object would be serialise to JSON, it already does this, its more about having getting the values to become properties of the array

Comment: // Current JSON

"CategoryScores": [
      {
        "CategoryId": "ALLCAT",
        "TraqCategoryScore": "53.89720374"
      },
      {
        "CategoryId": "CHI0001",
        "TraqCategoryScore": "20.04790595"
      }
 ]

 // Wanted Json

 "CategoryScores": [
        "ALLCAT": "53.89720374",
        "CHI0001": "20.04790595"
 ]

Comment: @RobPaddock add the serializing code.

Comment: Im using Web Api so its just in the config
 var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;

Comment: So create your own model class that matches what you are looking for and transform the data you pull from you DB. Don't return `CategoryScoresDTO`, but return your own model instead.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, but thats the problem I have I don't know how to write that model as their could be any number of categories.  In Javascript this would be simple. The properties are not known until the result is returned

Comment: You can just return an anonymous type and just call `Json(result)`.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to something like this in a WebApi controller.

```
private IHttpActionResult GetCatgoryScoresByBrandId(string brandId)
    {

        var scores = from s in db.CategoryScoresModel
                     where s.BrandId == brandId
                     select new CategoryScoresDTO()
                     {
                         CategoryId = s.CategoryId,
                         TraqCategoryScore = s.TraqCategoryScore
                     };

        return Json(scores);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice, but in the end I needed to return a Dictionary Object to get the desired result

```
private Dictionary<string, string> GetCatgoryScoresByBrandId(string brandId)
    {

        var scores = from s in db.CategoryScoresModel
                     where s.BrandId == brandId
                     select new CategoryScoresDTO()
                     {
                         CategoryId = s.CategoryId,
                         TraqCategoryScore = s.TraqCategoryScore,

                     };

        Dictionary<string, string> categoryScores = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        categoryScores = scores.ToDictionary(x => x.CategoryId, x => x.TraqCategoryScore);


        return categoryScores;
    }
```